# How to write this javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to run a regex check using javascript to be sure that the string follows the pattern:

NNNN-NN-NN

(where N = any number 0-9) I need to be sure the dashes are in place as well.

So, any 4 numbers followed by a dash followed by any 2 numbers followed by a dash followed by any two numbers.

How do I write that as a regex?

Comment: What have you tried? This regex is very simple and straightforward, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here it is:

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: +1, but no need to escape the hyphens here.

Comment: curious that this is getting so many upvotes - it's inadequate on two counts - no `^$` anchors, and no use of `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: i.e. it also matches `"oh-look-1234-56-78-I-forgot-to-anchor-my-regexp"`

Comment: You're right too, edited `:)`

Answer (score 4):

The simplest regexp is just:

```
/^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d$/
```

[ `\d\d` is shorter than `\d{2}` ]

You mustn't forget to anchor the regexp otherwise it'll match all strings *containing* that pattern, not just those exactly matching it.

For extra goodness, if you plan to subsequently extract the three components, use this:

```
var re = /^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)$/;
var test = "1234-56-78";
var vals = test.match(re);

// vals = ['1234-56-78', '1234', '56', '78'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}
```

I think the above regex would be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
I think this is fairly concise